# How to run the pdf.js node examples?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to run the pdf.js [node examples](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/node), e.g. [getinfo.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js). However it fails with

```
C:\Repositories\pdf.js>node getinfo.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Repositories\pdf.js\getinfo.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Repositories\pdf.js\getinfo.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Repositories\\pdf.js\\getinfo.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

This is what I did before:

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git
cd pdf.js
npm install
npm install -g gulp-cli
gulp generic
gulp generic-legacy
cd examples
cd node
node getinfo.js -> gives error mentioned above
```

So, how to get the node examples running? Also, why is it 'pdfjs-dist/**legacy**/build/pdf.js'? Can one update to the current version / is there an up to date example to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install `pdfjs-dist`. Alternatively that might work too:

> Run `gulp dist-install` to generate 'pdfjs-dist' npm package files.

I could adapt the sample and change

`const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js");`
to
`const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js");`

without any issues (for `getinfo.js`)